# Check if value exists in database c#/.net

Tags: c#, html, .net, checkbox

I am sending form data to a sql database and I display the outputs from my users in another form. I just added a checkbox field and I set the values at 'Y' and 'N' for yes and no. I am able to save them and retrieve it but I am trying to bind that value to a checkbox field in the form.

So my question is how can I display the value of the field for that specific item in the database in my checkbox field?

Here is what I have so far and it hasn't worked:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    Connection connection = new Connection();
    try
    {
        connection.connection1();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select Image,UserName,Description,Private,CompValue FROM FutureProjTbl Where id='" + projectId + "'", connection.con);
        SqlDataReader dataReader = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            image1.Src = dataReader["Image"].ToString();
            Owner.Text = dataReader["UserName"].ToString();
            Description.Text = dataReader["Description"].ToString();
            //The following 2 are my attempts to retrieve the item and bind it to the checkbox on the project template all the values will load into.
            //privateItem.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["Private"].ToString());
            //privateItem = (CheckBox) dataReader["Private"];
            compValue.Text = dataReader["CompValue"].ToString();


            FillDataForEditProjectModal(dataReader);
        }
        dataReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should consider using an ORM like Entity Framework, it makes your life a lot easier when it comes to operations like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to compare and return a boolean to set the checked value

```
privateItem.Checked = (dataReader["Private"].ToString() == "Y");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
privateItem.Checked = dataReader["Private"] == null ? false : dataReader["Private"].ToString() == "Y";
```

But instead of storing the value as `Y` and `N` why not change that field into a bool in the database and then you can just save it as the checked state of the checkbox (ie `true` for `Y`, `false` for `N`) and will map a lot easier when you bring it back:

```
privateItem.Checked = (bool)dataReader["Private"];
```

Comment: Thank you for the point on Boolean in the db, I couldn't figure out what I was missing and why he wouldn't have done that in the first place. Maybe I wasn't alone after all.